# Limited to one upload in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I've had this problem on a client's computer for nearly a year now... Windows 7 with the latest version of Chrome and IE. Whenever I try to upload multiple files to a Gmail attachment, Facebook, etc. it only lets me select one file.

I've cleared cache, reinstalled Chrome, ran CCleaner, checked Adobe settings, etc. to no avail.

Finally, yesterday I "reset" IE in the "Internet Options" (even though she never uses IE, i thought it would be worth a try)... restarted the computer and it started working again!

However, by today, it was back to only allowing for one file upload at a time.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you reset IE again, does it work again?  Does it behave the same way for any user that logs into that system?  Is this a company computer? Group Policy may be messing with the Internet settings.

Comment: I reset IE again and it worked... this time only for about an hour (last time it seemed to work for at least 12 hours). There aren't any other user accounts, but I could create one to try it. This isn't a company computer so no group policy.

Comment: Something is changing something, and if there's no GP in effect, then I'd suspect an infection.  Try a fresh new user, see how it goes. If the problem goes away, it's something in your user profile.  Disable all 3rd party start-ups and services (see `MSconfig`) and use it for a while like that, to see if things continue flip back to a non-working state. If not, enable them again one at a time until you find the culprit. It's a PITA, but the alternative would be a fresh reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem (6 months later) by removing Shrink Pic software from running. Shrink Pic is meant to compress photos as you upload them to web-based email or other sites so you that could share many photos at once. Apparently in doing so, it blocks multi-file upload for all sites.

Uninstalling the software resolved the issue.